# Webform/SwiftMailer - TypeError in encodeString() - must be of the type string, array given

Tags: webforms

I got into an issue while using a combination of SwiftMailer and Webform on Drupal 9. I found nothing helpfull while Googling and it took me a few days to figure out the issue. Hence I am sharing my findings with you.

**My context:**

- Drupal 9.1.3
- Webform 6.0.2 - with an Email Notification Handler
- MailSystem 8.x-4.3 - Module: Webform / Formatter: Swift Mailer /
  Sender: Swift Mailer
- Swift Mailer 8.x-2.0 - set up to send SMTP emails

**The problem:**

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Swift_AddressEncoder_IdnAddressEncoder::encodeString() must be of the type string, array given, called in /home/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php on line 378 in Swift_AddressEncoder_IdnAddressEncoder->encodeString() (line 32 of vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/AddressEncoder/IdnAddressEncoder.php).
```

**How the problem manifested:**

- the error above was displayed on the website's footer
- none of the AJAX driven features of the website didn't work - the ones from the admin interface, nor the ones in the front-end

Answer (score 0):

**The cause and my solution:**

In the Webform's email handler configuration -> "*Send from (website/domain)*" section -> "*From email*" field, I used the `[site:mail]` token.

In **EsmtpTransport.php** line 378, the $address parameter had a value of `["email@example.com" => string(0)]`.

By modifying the "*From email*" field to "*Site email address*" solved my problem.

Hope this helps.